# Is there an idiom for "if this image doesn't exist, build it"

Tags: buildah

I am using `buildah` to build [container images](https://opencontainers.org/).

I want to build an image, but only if one doesn't exist. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do this is

```bash
IMAGE=localhost/yourimage
buildah images -q "$IMAGE" >/dev/null 2>&1 || buildah unshare build_image.sh
```

Alternatively,

```bash
IMAGE=localhost/yourimage
if ! buildah images -q "$IMAGE" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "Building";
  whatever
fi;
```